# rails rspec shared examples for with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have these shared_examples_for method for testing authentication for controllers.

**support/controllers/authentication_helpers.rb**

```
module ControllerHelpers
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  shared_examples_for 'authenticate user' do |user, method, action, url_params={}|
    before(:each) do 
      setup_controller_for_warden
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
    it "should redirect visitors to login page" do
      sign_out user
      if method == :get
        get action, url_params
      elsif method == :post
        post action, url_params
      elsif method == :put
        put action, url_params
      elsif method == :delete
        delete action, url_params
      end
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
    it "should allow user" do
      sign_in user
      if method == :get
        get action, url_params
      elsif method == :post
        post action, url_params
      elsif method == :put
        put action, url_params
      elsif method == :delete
        delete action, url_params
      end
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

And I want to use it with my controller spec file.

**brief_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BriefController do
  render_views

  before(:all) do
    @customer=Factory(:customer)
    @project=Factory(:project_started, :owner => @customer)
  end

  context 'get :new' do
    it_behaves_like 'authenticate user', @customer, :get, :new, {:project_id => @project.to_param} 
  end
end
```

When I run these spec file, I encounter the error

```
Failure/Error: sign_in user
     RuntimeError:
       Could not find a valid mapping for
```

Do you know how can I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but I think that:

```
@customer=Factory(:customer)
@project=Factory(:project_started, :owner => @customer)
```

should be:

```
@customer=FactoryGirl(:customer)
@project=FactoryGirl(:project_started, :owner => @customer)
```

Simple mistake, I've made it myself a few times. Try it out and see if it fixes the problem, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I used these lines in all my model specs and it works without error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the arguments to `it_behaves_like` get evaluated before the `before` code gets executed, so the first argument (`@user`) evaluates to `nil`, causing further problems. I wasted many hours chasing this issue with my own code.

On a related point, I read a suggestion recently to avoid using instance variables in these kinds of tests because you want references to them to fail when they're not defined. It made sense to me and that's what I do now.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with using let block for instance variables.

```
shared_examples_for 'authenticate user' do |method, action|
    before(:each) do 
      setup_controller_for_warden
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
    it "should redirect visitors to login page" do
      if method == :get
        get action, url_params
      elsif method == :post
        post action, url_params
      elsif method == :put
        put action, url_params
      elsif method == :delete
        delete action, url_params
      end
      response.should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
```

**controller_spec.rb**

```
context 'get :new' do
    it_behaves_like 'authenticate user', :get, :new do 
      let(:user) { @customer }
      let(:url_params) { { :project_id => @project.to_param } }
    end
  end
```